# Uma nova tab no stackoverflow

Tags: novo-recurso

Seria legal e bem interessante se tivesse uma tab referente as perguntas chamada: `mais visitadas` como por exemplo as [`mais votadas`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes) na tela inicial

Comment: Não é grandes coisas, mas dá pra pesquisar, por exemplo, [posts com menos de 100 views](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=views%3A..100).

Comment: @brasofilo Ou ainda os [posts com **mais** de 100 views](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=views%3A100..).

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal, considerando que todo mundo aqui é programador, eu imaginava que `<=` levaria ao `>=` ;)